# How to set placeholder to dropdown in contact form 7?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I am new to WordPress contact form 7 plugin and I need to add this to my contact form.. Anybody can help me please?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per contact form 7 [setting placeholder](https://contactform7.com/setting-placeholder-text/). You can use the placeholder option for the following types of form tags: text, email, url, tel, textarea, number, range, date, and captchar.

But its little bit tricky for adding custom placeholder in dropdown. Sometimes we need match custom designed form with contact form but for adding placeholder in dropdown,[enter link description here](http://www.programmingscripts.com/how-to-add-placeholder-text-in-contact-form-7-dropdown/)You need to add some extra code in your theme functions.php
Here is filter that will add custom placeholder in contact form 7 dropdown menu.

Hope this will help you to add custom placeholder, happy coding !!!

Comment: If it's useful and working. Please upvote for the answer. @SandiT